# What is the easiest way to add a row in a UITableView with a user-provided string?

Tags: iphone, uitableview

I have a simple `UITableViewController` in a `UINavigationController` that displays a list of strings from an array with the default Edit/Done button on the right-hand side of the navigation bar.

When pressing the Edit button, the `UITableView` animates correctly and shows the red minus icons to delete. Pressing the delete button removes the row from the table view and the array (implemented in the `tableView:commitEditingStyle:forRowAtIndexPath:` method of the `UITableViewController`).

I would now like to allow the user to add a row to the view (and add the string to the underlying array), but I'm not sure how to go about doing so. The commitEditingStyle method has `else if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleInsert)`, but I don't know how I can get the user to input the string.

I've read the Table View Programming Guide (more specifically [the example of adding a table-view row](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/TableView_iPhone/ManageInsertDeleteRow/ManageInsertDeleteRow.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007451-CH10-SW5)), but this seems to require a whole new `UIViewController` subclass just to get a string from the user.

Is there no easier way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Creating another view controller is probably going to be the easiest way in the long run. You can present it modally by calling

```
SomeViewController* theViewController = [[SomeViewController alloc] init];
[self presentModalViewController: theViewController animated: YES];
[theViewController release];
```

When the theViewController is ready to go away it can call

```
[[self parentViewController] dismissModalViewControllerAnimated: YES];
```

OR 
you can setup a protocol for your new view controller so it can notify your original view controller of completion and send a value back, if you wanted an NSString back you might use

```
@protocol MyViewControllerDelegate
- (void)myViewControllerDelegate: (MyViewController*)myViewController didFinishWithValue: (NSString*)theString;
@end
```

MyViewController would then have a delegate property

```
@interface MyViewController
{
    id<MyViewControllerDelegate> delegate;
}
@property(nonatomic,assign) id<MyViewControllerDelegate> delegate;
@end
```

If you use the protocol method your original view controller will adopt that protocol and will dismiss the modal view itself when it receives this message.

I hope that helps out, it may seem a little complicated at first, but it makes gathering data very easy.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a UIAlertView or similar class yourself.  Just pop up the modal view to request the string, establish the right callbacks, then pop it in your dataSource.

You can also insert a cell with a UITextView and a "Tap to Edit" placeholder, then on the textView Callbacks, remove the textView and display the string.  Further editing would need to drill down or do something else